# Error, evento de JQuery se repite cuando la dataTable se recarga

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Buen día, he creado un DataTable desconectada con Jquery con los eventos comunes de ingresar, editar y eliminar. tengo un error cuando ingreso un dato, lo edito o lo elimino este lo hace correctamente recargando la Datatable, pero cuando intento nuevamente eliminar una row de la tabla este evento se repite mostrándome el dato que quiero eliminar correcto pero cuando se elimina vuelve y sale el evento de eliminar mostrándome un dato que no he seleccionado.

```js
this.getContextMenu = function (row) {
            var menu = [];    
            if (row.AU_RequiereValidacionAdmin && window.tienePermisoAdmin === true) {
                var validar = { title: 'Validar Ausencia', icon: 'fa-check-square-o', event: juniper.specialProjects.intranet.ausenciaUsuario.validarAbs };
                menu.push(validar);
            };                 
            var edit = { title: 'Editar Ausencia', icon: 'fa-pencil-square-o', event: juniper.specialProjects.intranet.ausenciaUsuario.editAbs};
            menu.push(edit);
            var eliminar = { title: 'Eliminar Ausencia', icon: 'fa-trash-o', event: juniper.specialProjects.intranet.ausenciaUsuario.eliminarAbs};
            menu.push(eliminar);           
            return menu;
        };
        
        //***********************************************************************
          this.eliminarAbs = function (row) {        
            alert(row.Id_STI + " - - " + row.Id_incidencia);
            var message = String.format('¿Desea eliminar la Ausencia <strong>{0} - {1}</strong><br/>con fechas <strong>[{2}] - [{3}]</strong>?', row.Id_incidencia, row.I_asumpte, _toNullableDateString(row.AU_fechaInicio), _toNullableDateString(row.AU_fechaFin));
            $.sweetModal.confirm(message, function () {
                _deleteAbs(row.Id_incidencia);
            });
        };
        var _deleteAbs = function (id) {
            var data = {};
            data.idInc = id;
            data.op = 'deleteAbs';
            $.ajax({
                url: window.baseUrl + "url",
                async: true,
                data: data,
                dataType: "json",
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result.StatusOk) {                        
                        juniper.specialProjects.intranet.Notifications.showSuccessNotification("Ausencia eliminada correctamente");
                        _reloadFilters();
                    } else {
                        juniper.specialProjects.intranet.Notifications.showErrorNotification(result.ErrorMessage);
                    }
                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    juniper.specialProjects.intranet.Notifications.showErrorNotification("Se ha producido un error eliminando la ausencia " + id);
                }
            });
        };
        //*************************************************************************************
            //*************************************************************************************
        var _reloadFilters = function (initialPage) {
            var divload = $("<div />").attr({
                id: "tableLoadingBottom",
                class: "tableLoading"
            }).html('<div><img src="' + window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.hostname + 'loading"></div>');
            $("#it_table_AusenciasUsuario .junTableSupCont").prepend(divload);
            _getAbsencesTable();
        };
        //*************************************************************************************
```

1- elimino una row de la DataTable
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
2- al intentar eliminar de nuevo, al dar aceptar o cancelar muestra un siguiente dato para eliminar sin que yo lo escoja, repitiendo el evento.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

alguien puede orientarme como puedo solucionar este error, el cual solo sucede en la tabla desconectada que he creado. agradeceria mucho.

Comment: hola, será mejor que puedas ejemplificar con dibujos o screenshots? no puedo replicar el error que estás teniendo

Comment: Gracias, he actualizado con algunas capturas de lo que esta sucediendo, no se si me hago entender. un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

La api de Datatablejs tiene listas funciones para trabajar con las tablas.

con [`tabla.clear().draw()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/clear()) elimina los registros al momento conservando la configuración previa.

Comment: Creo, si no estoy equivocado, que él se refiere a cuando manda una alerta para eliminar enseguida de darle aceptar o cancelar le salta otra alerta igual como si le hubiera dado click para eliminar otra vez desde su misma tabla.

Comment: Oh! callbackhell

Comment: Tal vez los eventos de tu menú se estén propagando a través del DOM incorrectamente y las llamadas se estén disparando de una manera "involuntaria", no conozco mucho del API de datatables, pero por experiencia propia, cuando completabla incorrectamente un selector con jquery en algunos casos me sucedia eso mismo, se disparaban doble los eventos.